# GPU acceleration using transform:translateZ(0) and text disappear when color is white

Tags: html, css

My project in some part need GPU acceleration to make a fast translation, but when I active the GPU acceleration using `-webkit-transform:translateZ(0)` in CSS, I see that the color becomes lighter, and white letters disappears completely in any background. When I setting up the color of letter to #CCC or #DDD, it hardly can be observed.

Any solution to fix this problem?

**Example:**

[image: GPU disabled]

[image: GPU enabled]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, solved by myself..

After a night thinking about it, I figured out that the reason to disappear the text and the text color are being lighter maybe is due by the anisotropic or antialiasing of the text, so I disabled the anisotropic by adding `text-rendering:optimizespeed` in the CSS and woala! Problem solved.

Comment: You'll likely find that this problem goes away over time - I suspect that in the Canary builds of Chrome for instance that this may have been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

We ran into this problem when using GPU-acceleration in combination with text-rendering:optimizeLegibility. Not declaring text-rendering in general was the solution to this problem in our case.